# Grails logging configuration with different appenders

Tags: grails, log4j

This is my current log4j configuration. The problem is the development specific part.

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        console name:'stdout',
                threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.ERROR

        rollingFile name: "appenderAccessLog",
 ...                    
        rollingFile name: "appenderAppLog",
    ...              

        environments {
            development{
                rollingFile name: "appenderDebugLog",
                    threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG,
                    ....
            }
        }

    }


    error       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
                'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
                'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
                'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
                'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
                'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
                'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
                'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
                'org.springframework',
                'org.hibernate',
                'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'



    environments {
        production {
            // Override previous setting for 'grails.app.controller'
            root {
                error 'appenderAppLog','stdout'
                additivity = false
            }

        }              
                  debug additivity: false, stdout :['mycompany',
                     'mycompany.security',
                     'mycompany.common',
                     'grails.app.services.mycompany.services']

            debug additivity: false, appenderDebugLog :['mycompany',
                'mycompany.security',
                'mycompany.common',
                'grails.app.services.mycompany.services']

            root {
                error 'appenderAppLog','stdout'
                additivity = true
            }
```

Now above you see 2 debug statements with specific package redirections to appenders.
Now if I want to use debug for package XXX and send to appender A and B i am forced to use above definition - its a repetition of  debugg appender1: XXX and debug appender2: XXX package.

I checked the grails log - Ideally the below should work to resolve the additional debug/appender statements:
                        error org.springframework

```
                    debug mycompany.packagenames...

        root {
            error 'appenderAppLog','stdout'
                            debug 'appenderDebugLog', 'stdout'
            additivity = true
        }
```

But what actually happens when I do that is all the packages listed in error category - start sending the debug messages  to the appenderDebugLog file. When I have explicitly stated different packages when defining each level as in the top - why should the debug configuration in the Root appender create this issue?.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's the case but possibly moving all package specifications below `appenders` and `root` sections would help.
Also specifying `stdout` with both `error` and `debug` within root looks redundant.

And there is an option to specify appender-specific definitions (e.g. http://snipplr.com/view/63391/grails-log4j-for-different-environments--an-example/ ) for fine-grained configuration.

Comment: Tried moving all packages below appenders and root - and still the same behavior is observed. Will try the link next.

Answer (score 0):

In my testing with Grails 2, the `environments` section inside the `log4j` section does not seem to work with appenders. You can, however, create separate `log4j` configurations in the root `environments` section, although unfortunately this means you'll have to duplicate everything, e.g.

```
environments {
    development {
        log4j {
            console name:'stdout',
                threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.ERROR

            rollingFile name: "appenderAccessLog",

            rollingFile name: "appenderAppLog",

            rollingFile name: "appenderDebugLog",
                threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.DEBUG,
                ....
    }
    production {
        log4j {
            console name:'stdout',
                threshold: org.apache.log4j.Level.ERROR

            rollingFile name: "appenderAccessLog",

            rollingFile name: "appenderAppLog",
        }
    }
}
```

https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.5.x/guide/conf.html#environments